# How to create a new shortcut for MS PowerPoint 2010?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I use the text box(Alt → N → X) a lot. I was wonder if its possible to create a new Ctrl shortcut for text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-keyboard-shortcuts-9a92343e-a781-4d5a-92f1-0f32e3ba5b4d?CorrelationId=ea987303-1651-41d9-b9c5-12a9453be10a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) has step by step explanation to create shortcut.

Update:

---

Apparently, Steve is correct! "*You can customize the quick access toolbar to add a Horizontal or Vertical text box button though.*" but, can't customize shortcut keys in ppt. There should be some add in's out there.

Comment: I did see this document earlier, but the instruction seems to be incorrect. Many of the things I am told to click do not exist.

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of that link and you'll see that it says "Applies to:  Word 2010".  Word's always allowed customizing shortcut keys, but PPT hasn't.  You can customize the quick access toolbar to add a Horizontal or Vertical text box button though.

Comment: Chirag Dalal has some interesting add-ins, including this one that may help:  http://officeone.mvps.org/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr.html